# Boolean variable Explanation

Tags: java

I have a question about this block of Java code. (Yes, I am a beginner). The code works, I am just a little confused. This code checks the people and cars arrays to find if it has empty seats, which is what the tryToAdd method does. It will then add the person to that car. My question is about the boolean values. It looks to me that added is set to false. Then in the for loop it says: as long as added is true..do the loop. So, it seems that the loop should never run.

```
public void loadPassengers() {
    for (Person p : people) {
        boolean added = false;
        for (int i = 0; !added && i < cars.size(); i++) {
            added = cars.get(i).tryToAdd(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check "!" (NOT) operator in loop it makes the added=false to true, if the value of added is true then the loop would never run

Comment: The condition in the for loop says: as long as added is **false** (and `i` is smaller than the number of cars), do the loop.

Comment: How come you don't see the ! operator before added variable in loop

Comment: I think what I was trying to get at is:   does !added mean added = true; or does !added mean !added==false;

Answer (score 3):

> Then in the for loop it says: as long as added is true

Actually, it says the opposite of that. Look again:

```
for (int i = 0; !added && i < cars.size(); i++)
```

`!` is the 'logical inverse' (or `not`) operator. So this statement is actually saying 'stay in the for loop so long as we haven't added and i is less than the size of cars'.

Presumably, at some point `cars.get(i).tryToAdd(p)` will return `true`, and the for loop will terminate. Or you run out of `cars`. Either way the loop runs for at least one iteration (so long as you have at least one car).

Answer (score 0):

`!` is inverse of boolean.

You are executing a loop to say that unless a person is added (`tryToAdd(p)` which returns true) execute the loop. And also `i < cars.size()` says cars should have seat to add person.

Added explanation in your code.

```
public void loadPassengers() {
    boolean added; //Declaring added variable outside for loop for memory management
    for (Person p : people) { //Execute loop for each person
        added = false; //setting added value to false for each person

        // unless person is added execute the loop and also check for the car size.
        for (int i = 0; (added == false && i < cars.size()); i++) { // added == false or !added is same
            added = cars.get(i).tryToAdd(p); // tryToAdd(p) return true to confirm that a person is added
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You confused it. Actually,

```
if(!added)
{
  //code
}
```

This condition is equal to:

```
if(added == false)
{
   //code
}
```

So your logic says, `as long as *added* is false, keep iterating, and try to perform' added = cars.get(i).tryToAdd(p);  ,`setting value of added to 'true'`